# basic bonjour java IP address resolution

Tags: java, ip-address, bonjour

I'm using bonjour (with java) to try to get IP addresses for devices on a network.  I've looked at this question: [Get Device IP with Bonjour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243093/get-device-ip-with-bonjour) and am using the InetAdress getByName method (with a resolved host) to get an IP address.

The problem is that this IP address I get doesn't match anything I know about the device!  what I really want is the local router assigned IP address of the device.  (in this case it's 192.168.1.146) what I'm getting instead (consistently, every time) is 208.68.xxx.xx

the latter address doesn't seem to be my WAN IP,  and I have no idea what it really is...  I get that address consistently for every device I connect to... any help would be appreciated!  (maybe I need to translate the IP address somehow?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName)`  instead of `InetAddress.getByName(hostName)`-

The device(s) hostname resolves to more than one IP address.  The above address returned was actually the search page for my ISP-  which obviously is not useful.